# Storing JSON output from multiple individual API calls into Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: json, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Pyspark newbie here, currently working in Azure Databricks, using a single cluster with 8 cores.

I have a Pyspark dataframe (call this 'df'), where each entry is a property (house/apartment), and has columns for longitude and latitude. The entire dataframe has about 6 million rows.

| longitude | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 97 |
| 36 | 95 |
| ... | ... |

I also have access to an API which, given longitude and latitude, outputs a JSON object containing information about that property (square footage, footprint, roof condition, etc). The output looks something like this ("structures" has a [] around it for some reason):

{"request_id":12345,"structures":[{"footPrint":{"area":275,"wkt":"-83.8 35.9"},"roof_condition":{"value":3.0}],"property_features":{"parcel_wkt":"-83.7 35.9", "requested_wkt":"-83.6 35.9"}}

My question is - How can I most efficiently construct a Pyspark dataframe like the following?

| longitude | latitude | request_id | area | wkt | roof_condition | parcel_wkt | requested_wkt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 97 | 12345 | 275 | -83.8 35.9 | 3.0 | -83.7 35.9 | -83.6 35.9 |
| 36 | 95 | 12346 | 280 | -81.5 35.4 | 5.0 | -82.0 36.1 | -81.1 35.0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I have tried -

1. Create a function to process a single row of the dataframe, then use a UDF with withColumn. For 100 rows, this took over half an hour.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def process_row(longitude, latitude):

    # Use API call to get attributes associated with each lat/lon coordinate
    url = 'https://api-url.com/GetInfo?wkt=POINT({} {})&format=json&token=mytoken'.format(longitude, latitude)
    data = get_api_info(url) # grabs the output of the API call as a json object

    return (data['request_id'], \
            data['structures'][0]['footPrint']['area'], \
            data['structures'][0]['footprint']['wkt'], \
            data['structures'][0]['roof_condition']['value'], \
            data['property_features']['parcel_wkt'], \
            data['property_features']['requested_wkt'])

schema = StructType([  
    StructField("request_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("area", FloatType(), True),  
    StructField("wkt", StringType(), True),
    StructField("roof_condition", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("parcel_wkt", StringType(), True),
    StructField("requested_wkt", StringType(), True)
])

process_row_udf = udf(process_row, schema)
df_ret = df.withColumn('output', process_row_udf('longitude', 'latitude'))
display(df_ret)
```

2. Use withColumn to create a single new column 'json_data', which consists of the entire json object as a string. My idea was to then use pyspark.sql.functions.from_json to add new columns from the now existing 'json_data' column to create the request_id, area, wkt, roof_condition, parcel_wkt, and requested_wkt columns. But the first half of this idea was already taking too long (5 minutes for only 30 rows), so I gave up on the rest :(

```
def process_row2(longitude, latitude):

    # Use API call to get attributes associated with each lat/lon coordinate
    url = 'https://api-url.com/GetInfo?wkt=POINT({} {})&format=json&token=mytoken'.format(longitude, latitude)
    data = get_api_info(url) # grabs the output of the API call as a json object
          
    return str(data)

process_row2_udf = udf(process_row2, StringType())
df_ret2 = df.withColumn('json_data', process_row2_udf('longitude', 'latitude'))
display(df_ret2)
```

Ideally, I would like to process several rows per second, maybe 3-5, on average. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm confused as to why this is so slow, since I'm pretty sure running a sequential for loop in Pandas is fast than this. I have also checked that the API call itself runs in a fraction of a second, so that's not the bottleneck here. And since I have over 6 million rows to process, I really need this to complete in a reasonable amount of time. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: How many executors are started? Can the API handle millions of requests in quick succession?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I just tested 30 API calls in quick succession, which took a total of about 17 seconds. As for the number of executors, sorry I'm noob, is this what you mean?

(5) Spark Jobs
Job 50 View(Stages: 1/1)
Job 51 View(Stages: 1/1)
Job 52 View(Stages: 1/1)
Job 53 View(Stages: 1/1, 2 skipped)
Job 54 View(Stages: 1/1, 4 skipped)

Comment: Okay, so 1) About 2 per second... But does 300 calls take near 170 seconds? 3000 calls in 1700? When does that stop becoming linear? Will you DDOS the API? 2) Seems like there is only one executor stage, so Spark is not distributing your data. Look at `--num-executors` option - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html